fit a curve to a shape that the plot has

I want to draw a curve that delimits the U-shape that this potential has. How do I do that. The code is:
frequencies_first=trajec_first['r'].value_counts().sort_index()
probabilities_first=frequencies_first/frequencies_first.sum()
energies_first=-np.log(probabilities_first)
energies_first0=energies_first.index-radious
plt.plot(energies_first0, energies_first.values, '^', label='5min')
plt.xlabel('r (micron)')
plt.ylabel('energia (kT)')
plt.legend()

plt.show()

I try to do the curve as the u-shape but i dont know how.

There could be many ways to do this, but what first comes to mind is to use the "convex hull" of the points. The top being flat should mean all the points will lie around the path of what looks to me like a quadratic curve.
I don't have your data to test with, but here's an idea of how it might look:
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import numpy as np
...
points = np.array([energies_first0, energies_first.values]).T  # lay out points in correct order (columns are xy, rows are each point)
hull = ConvexHull(points)

hull_x = points[hull.vertices,0]  # hull vertices are indexes into list of input points
hull_y = points[hull.vertices,1]
plt.plot(hull_x, hull_y, 'ro')  # plot the points for visual confirmation

fit = np.polyfit(hull_x, hull_y, 2)  # 2nd order polynomial fit assumes no points were made across flat top of the profile. May need to check hull.coplanar to trim values?

fit_x = np.linspace(hull_x.min(), hull_x.max())
poly = np.poly1d(fit)
fit_y = poly(fit_x)

plt.plot(fit_x, fit_y, "b-')

Note: if the true curve is a higher order polynomial or something like a Gaussian distribution, convex hull may not be quite appropriate. Any inflection points where the curve is concave won't be properly measured because the convex hull will effectively truncate that portion of the curve to be flat rather than concave.
An alternative approach which takes not simply the outer shape, but the density distribution of the data points could be to create a 2D histogram of the points, and plot the density contours. Picking a specific contour threshold could give a series of points on which you could fit higher polynomials or non-polynomial functions.
Final Thoughts: It looks like you have a quantized system where there exists some probability to select a particular energy level as well as within each energy level a probability distribution of radii. I would assume these distributions may be separable, and could be represented by separate 1D functions, however this is quickly going past my actual physics knowledge.

I think a OneClassSVM would work here. They are usually used for unsupervised outlier detection, i.e. they separate the outlier points automatically.
In this case, we can view the edges of the mass as outlier points, and fit an SVM to draw a boundary along the curvature. The main hyperparameters to tune for the SVM are gamma= which controls how smooth the boundary is, and nu= which controls how far into the mass we want the boundary to be. I found 0.1 to work well for the test data below.
The figure below shows the test data I synthesised (grey points), along with the SVM's decision values (green) and the decision boundary (red). I discretised the decision boundary to yield the black contour.

I histogram along the energia axis in order to locate the constant-energia densities, and clip them off (yellow region). Finally, I fit a quadratic to the remaining points (red).

The amount of clipping at the edges can be tweaked with exaggerate_clip - it's better to clip more aggressively than to under-clip, so that the resulting points don't distort the polynomial fit.
You can increase poly_degree to get a closer (more irregular) fit to the black contour.
Reproducible example
Synthesise test data:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#Useful for Intel processors (speed up sklearn)
#from sklearnex import patch_sklearn
#patch_sklearn()

#Data for testing
np.random.seed(10)
row0_x = np.random.uniform(-3, 3, size=500)
row0_y = np.full_like(row0_x, 13)

row1_x = np.random.uniform(-2.5, 2.5, size=500)
row1_y = np.full_like(row1_x, 12.5)

row2_x = np.random.uniform(-2.1, 2.4, size=500)
row2_y = np.full_like(row2_x, 12.23)

row3_x = np.random.uniform(-1.9, 2.3, size=500)
row3_y = np.full_like(row3_x, 12)

bulk1 = np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 11.5], np.array([[0.6, 0], [0, 3]]), 5_000)
bulk2 = np.random.multivariate_normal([0, 11.5], np.array([[0.8, 0], [0, 3.5]]), 10_000)
bulk = np.row_stack([bulk1, bulk2])
bulk = bulk[bulk[:, 1] < 11.8]

bulk = bulk[np.linalg.norm(bulk - [0, 11.5], axis=1) < 7]

x = np.concatenate([row0_x, row1_x, row2_x, row3_x, bulk[:, 0]])
y = np.concatenate([row0_y, row1_y, row2_y, row3_y, bulk[:, 1]])
X = np.column_stack([x, y])

Fit one-class SVM:
from sklearn.svm import OneClassSVM

model = OneClassSVM(kernel='rbf', gamma=0.1, nu=0.1).fit(X)

Delineate boundaries and plot:
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 4))

#Scatter data
ax.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], marker='|', color='dimgray')

#Compute decision values
grid_res = 200
x_axis = np.linspace(X[:, 0].min() * 1.02, X[:, 0].max() * 1.02, grid_res)
y_axis = np.linspace(X[:, 1].min() * 0.98, X[:, 1].max() * 1.02, grid_res)
x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(x_axis, y_axis)
xy_grid = np.column_stack([x_grid.ravel(), y_grid.ravel()])

xy_scores = model.decision_function(xy_grid).reshape(x_grid.shape)

boundary_thickness = 1
boundary_ix_y, boundary_ix_x = np.where(
    (xy_scores > -boundary_thickness) & (xy_scores < boundary_thickness)
)
boundary_xy = np.column_stack([x_axis[boundary_ix_x], y_axis[boundary_ix_y]])

#Fill background with decision function values
im = ax.contourf(x_grid, y_grid, xy_scores, zorder=0, alpha=0.25, cmap='Greens_r')
im2 = ax.contour(x_grid, y_grid, xy_scores, cmap='Greens_r', linewidths=0.5, zorder=0)
cbar = f.colorbar(mappable=im, pad=0.01)
f.colorbar(mappable=im2, cax=cbar.ax, label='SVM decision value')

#plt.contour zero-boundary
# ax.contour(x_grid, y_grid, xy_scores, cmap='Greys_r', linewidths=10, levels=[0, 1e-7])

#Extracted boundary points
ax.scatter(boundary_xy[:, 0], boundary_xy[:, 1], color='black', marker='_', zorder=2)

#Optional: identify the data points closest to the boundary line
if False:
    distances = np.linalg.norm(X[:, None, :] - boundary_xy[None, :, :], axis=2)
    closest_ixs = np.argmin(distances, axis=0)
    closest_xy = np.column_stack([X[closest_ixs, 0], X[closest_ixs, 1]])
    ax.scatter(closest_xy[:, 0], closest_xy[:, 1], marker='|', color='magenta', zorder=2)

#Reject points above the flat densities
exaggerate_clip = 0.95 #clip before the edge starts (1.0 = at the edge)
counts, edges = np.histogram(X[:, 1], bins=len(X) // 30)
edges = edges[1:]
com = (counts / counts.sum() * edges).sum()
if False:
    plt.hist(X[:, 1], bins=len(X) // 30)
    plt.gcf().set_size_inches(5, 2)
    plt.gca().set(xlabel='energia (kT)', ylabel='counts')
first_gap = edges[edges > com][np.argmin(counts[edges > com])] * exaggerate_clip

boundary_xy_clipped = boundary_xy[boundary_xy[:, 1] < first_gap]
boundary_xy_rejects = boundary_xy[boundary_xy[:, 1] > first_gap]
ax.scatter(
    boundary_xy_rejects[:, 0], boundary_xy_rejects[:, 1],
    marker='_',  linewidth=25, color='yellow', s=400, alpha=0.1, zorder=0
)

#Final fit
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial

poly = Polynomial.fit(boundary_xy_clipped[:, 0], boundary_xy_clipped[:, 1], deg=2)
ax_lims = plt.axis()
ax.plot(x_axis, poly(x_axis), color='red', linewidth=3)
ax.axis(ax_lims)

Plot formatting:
ax.spines[:].set_visible(False)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', left=False, bottom=False)
ax.set(xlabel=r'r ($\mu$m)', ylabel='energia (kT)')

#Legend
ax.scatter([], [], marker='|', linewidth=3, color='dimgray', label='data')
ax.scatter([], [], marker='|', linewidth=20, s=80, color='#f7f43b', label='rejection region')
ax.scatter([], [], marker='s',  color='black', label='discretised decision boundary')
ax.plot([], [], linewidth=3, color='red', label=f'polynomial fit (deg={poly.degree()})')
ax.legend(framealpha=0.6)

